# Python recursive to 5 levels for dirs and files

Tags: python-2.7, os.walk

I am looking for a more elegant solution to an issue I am facing when trying to recurse to multiple levels to list out dirs and files.

`os.walk(folder)` does sub and sub-sub levels, but I need to go to at least 5 deep.

I have come up with the following to traverse multiple directories, however, is there a better, or more elegant way that I am missing?

```py
rootPath = '/path/to/my/folder/test'

print '###### using os.walk ######'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    print 'directory - ' + " ".join(dirs)
    for d in dirs:
        for f in files:
            if not f.startswith('.'):
                print 'directory - ' + d + '  file - ' + f


print '\n\n\n###### using isdir ######'
for f in os.listdir(rootPath):
    print '-' + f
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(rootPath,f)):
        for fo in os.listdir(os.path.join(rootPath,f)):
            print '--' + fo
            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(rootPath,f,fo)):
                for fol in os.listdir(os.path.join(rootPath,f,fo)):
                    print '---' + fol
                    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(rootPath,f,fo,fol)):
                        for fold in os.listdir(os.path.join(rootPath,f,fo,fol)):
                            print '----' + fold
                            if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(rootPath,f,fo,fol,fold)):
                                for folde in os.listdir(os.path.join(rootPath,f,fo,fol,fold)):
                                    print '-----' + folde
                                    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(rootPath,f,fo,fol,fold,folde)):
                                        for folder in os.listdir(os.path.join(rootPath,f,fo,fol,fold,folde)):
                                            print '------' + folder
```

Output:

```
###### using os.walk ######
directory - first
directory - second
directory - third
directory - fourth
directory - fourth  file - in_third.txt
directory - fifth
directory - fifth  file - in_fourth.txt
directory - 


###### using isdir ######
-.DS_Store
-first
---.DS_Store
---second
-----.DS_Store
-----third
------.DS_Store
------fourth
-------.DS_Store
-------in_fourth.txt
-------fifth
---------.DS_Store
---------in_fifth.txt
------in_third.txt
```

It seems as though os.walk isn't going into the 'fifth' folder to see in_fifth.txt, however the isidr() solution does.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So part of this was my misunderstanding about how os.walk worked, I believed you were required to iterate through ever directory with `for d in dirs`. however, it seems it does it already with `for f in files`

I got round this by letting files do its thing, then replacing root with the rootPath I initially provided, as I only wanted the directory names after this entire path string.

```py
rootPath = '/path/to/my/folder/test'
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for f in files:
        if not f.startswith('.'):
            print 'file - ' + os.path.join(os.path.join(root.replace(rootPath,''), f))
```

Output:

```
file - /test2/first/foobar/files1.txt
file - /test2/first/foo.txt
file - /extra/test/bar.bin
```

Comment: FYI, `os.path.relpath(os.path.join(root,f),rootPath))` generates a path relative to `rootPath`.